# Evaluate the series which looks like a telescopic series but isn't one?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

> Evaluate$$\sum_{r=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(3r+1)(3r+2)}$$

Wolfram alpha gives the answer $\pi/(3\sqrt{3})$ so I know for sure that this requires multiple mathematical concepts like the taylor series which isn't the telescopic series.

I think complex numbers and the cube root of unity may have something to do with it due to the tricyclic nature of the series but I can't lay my finger on the approach.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct that the series does not telescope.  That said, a partial fraction decomposition can be used to evaluate the series:
$$\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)} = \frac{1}{3n+1} - \frac{1}{3n+2}$$
hence consider the function
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{3n} = \frac{1}{1-z^3}, \quad |z| < 1$$
whose antiderivative is
$$F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1} = \int_{t=0}^z \frac{1}{1-t^3} \, dt, \quad |z| < 1.$$
Similarly,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+2}}{3n+2} = \int_{t=0}^z \frac{t}{1-t^3} \, dt, \quad |z| < 1.$$
Put together,
$$S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3n+1}}{3n+1} - \frac{z^{3n+2}}{3n+2} = \int_{t=0}^z \frac{1-t}{1-t^3} \, dt, \quad |z| < 1.$$
Taking the limit as $z \to 1^+$ we obtain
$$\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)} \\
&= \int_{t=0}^1 \frac{1}{1+t+t^2} \, dt \\
&= \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \tan^{-1} \frac{1+2t}{\sqrt{3}} \right]_{t=0}^1 \\
&= \frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing with me this approach. I had one question: how does one think of the second step? is the approach taught in later years in calculus/algebra or was it purely intuition-based? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ekas The decision to generalize a series of the form $$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$$ into a power series $$S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$$ is a strategy commonly used in the theory of generating functions.  The idea to use antiderivatives/integration is something that comes with experience.  There are many such applications, and once you've seen it, you just remember.  A lot of mathematical problem solving is about being exposed to these "tricks" that can be added to one's repertoire of tools.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one way.
Let
$$
f(z) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3r+1}}{3r+1},\qquad
g(z) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{z^{3r+2}}{3r+2},
$$
for $|z|<1$, so that our answer is $L = \lim_{z\to 1^-}\big(f(z)-g(z)\big)$.
Now complute
$$
f'(z) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty z^{3r} = \frac{1}{1-z^3},\qquad
g'(z) = \sum_{r=0}^\infty z^{3r+1} = \frac{z}{1-z^3} .
$$
Integrate these to recover $f$ and $g$:
$$
f(z) =
-{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {3}}{18}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( 1-z \right) }{3}}+{
\frac {\ln  \left( {z}^{2}+z+1 \right) }{6}}+{\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3}
\arctan \left( {\frac { \left( 2\,z+1 \right) \sqrt {3}}{3}} \right) }
\\
g(z) = 
{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {3}}{18}}-{\frac {\ln  \left( 1-z \right) }{3}}+{
\frac {\ln  \left( {z}^{2}+z+1 \right) }{6}}-{\frac {\sqrt {3}}{3}
\arctan \left( {\frac { \left( 2\,z+1 \right) \sqrt {3}}{3}} \right) }
\\
f(z)-g(z) = 
-{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {3}}{9}}+{\frac {2\,\sqrt {3}}{3}\arctan \left( {
\frac {\sqrt {3} \left( 2\,z+1 \right) }{3}} \right) }
\\
L = \lim_{z\to 1^-}\big(f(z)-g(z)\big) =
-\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {3}}{9} +\frac {2\,\sqrt {3}}{3}\arctan(\sqrt{3}\,)
= \frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}
$$